# generating excel report from iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, excel

I am suppose to generate some excel reports from my app,i tried generating by using office open xml,i have read that if we save the xml file created with extension .xls,it will act like actual excel file,is this possible? Please help me to fix this issue or give some useful links for the tutorial.

Comment: hello everybody,i found solution for this i just created a html table and saved in .xls format this works fine

Answer (score 2):

Try exporting using a more straightforward [CSV format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) (which is easier to code up and can be easily opened into Excel).

Here's a [related question with some potentially useful information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159576/how-to-export-data-to-a-csv-file-with-iphone-sdk-3-0).

Comment: Hello Michael Dautermann,Thanks for your suggestion.I think if we use csv format we can not do formatting in the Excel sheet.